# EF 5 Connection Management

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Is it possible that EF5 does not immediately close connections when using a DBContext like

```
 public void UpdateCategory(Models.Category catData)
    {
        if (catData == null) return;
        using (var cntx = new DataContext())
        {
            //IN THE LINE BELOW A CONNECTION IS DEFINITELY OPENED BUT IS IT IMMEDIATELY CLOSE????
            var cat = cntx.Set<Category>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == catData.CategoryId);

            if (cat == null) return;

            if (!cat.LastChanged.Matches(catData.LastChanged))
                throw new ConcurrencyException(cat.GetType().ToString());

            cat.CategoryName = catData.CategoryName;

            cntx.DbContext.Entry<Category>(cat).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

            //AFTER THE NEXT LINE DO I HAVE 2 CONNECTIONS OPENED? OR WAS THE CONNECTION OPENED FROM THE FIRST QUERY CLOSED ALREADY?
            cntx.SaveChanges();


            catData.LastChanged = cat.LastChanged;
        }

    }
```

Are there scenerios\bugs where the same context creates\opens 2 connections, leaving one open?

Comment: How do you know you have 2 connections open? Activity Monitor? I wouldn't worry too much about EFs connection management, I'm pretty sure it's solid...

Comment: If the underlying connection is SQL, there's a lot that's happening by default without your knowledge: connection pooling, etc.  As Charleh suggested, I wouldn't worry too much about it - the standard generated context does a good job of handling connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb896325

> The Entity Framework opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.
>
> When a query method is called, the connection is opened, and it remains open until the ObjectResult has been completely consumed or disposed.

```
public void UpdateCategory(Models.Category catData)
{
    if (catData == null) return;
    using (var cntx = new DataContext())
    {
        //IN THE LINE BELOW A CONNECTION IS DEFINITELY OPENED BUT IS IT 
        //IMMEDIATELY CLOSE? => YES!
        var cat = cntx.Set<Category>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == catData.CategoryId);

        if (cat == null) return;

        if (!cat.LastChanged.Matches(catData.LastChanged))
            throw new ConcurrencyException(cat.GetType().ToString());

        cat.CategoryName = catData.CategoryName;

        cntx.DbContext.Entry<Category>(cat).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        //AFTER THE NEXT LINE DO I HAVE 2 CONNECTIONS OPENED? => NO
        cntx.SaveChanges();


        catData.LastChanged = cat.LastChanged;
    }

}
```

> Are there scenerios where the same context creates\opens 2 connections, leaving one open?

Yes, when using transaction with a DbContext it will open a second connection have a look here: http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/48/entity-framework-transactionscope-and-msdtc